# I have a scheduled a task which downloads a file and unzips it into resource folder. It works well normally but fails if I run it as JAR file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, file-handling

This is a spring boot project where I download a file from a URL, then unzip them and save them to the resource folder, from where the load function then reads the file. The current snippet shown below works perfectly well, but when I packaged it to a JAR file , it throws error that the path /src/main/resources/ is not found.

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 15000, fixedDelay = 60000)
    public void getFile() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ZipException {


        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL("https:some-url/file.zip"),
                new File("file.zip"), 60000, 60000);
        
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("file.zip");
        zipFile.extractAll("/src/main/resources");
        
        loadData.load(); 
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think `src/main/resources` would exist when you run your application? That is an artifact in your **sources**, not of the final compiled project.

Comment: Then what do you suggest Mark. What can be done?

Comment: Have your application create the right folders (and no, `/src/main/resources/` would not be the 'right' folders, especially not as an absolute path on Linux), eg in the user directory, or in the temp directory or whatever is appropriate for your application, and then download the file to that path.